# Routing mapping with ? in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue mapping to an route with custom parameters

**How do I render url is**

> $location.url('#/site/errors/0/50').search({
>                           'searchString':searchString
>                   });

which generates url as:

> /#/site/errors/0/50?searchString=test

**My route mapping**

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/:applicationName/errors/:pageNumber/:itemsPerPage/:searchMessage', { templateUrl: '/templates/ErrorList.html', controller: 'ErrorListController' })
    .when('/:applicationName/errors/:pageNumber/:itemsPerPage/?searchString=:searchMessage', { templateUrl: '/templates/ErrorList.html', controller: 'ErrorListController' })
```

I have an issue with binding the into the url.

binding doesnt work:

> /#/site/errors/0/50?searchString=test

binding does work

> /#/site/errors/0/50searchString=test

**Solution thnx to:Chandermani**

I have updated the mapping to:

> .when('/:applicationName/errors/:pageNumber/:itemsPerPage/', {
>   templateUrl: '/templates/ErrorList.html', controller:
>   'ErrorListController' })

And I can still access the parameter 'searchString' from $routeParams

Comment: I don't think routeParams and route binding works with querysting or search parameters. For getting the search parameters using `$location.search()`

Comment: @Chandermani can you promote your comment to answer? as this was the issue, which I did not know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think routeParams and route binding works with querysting or search parameters. For getting the search parameters using `$location.search()`